# How to add a field into an inherited view's tab/page?

Tags: odoo

How can I inherited a view to add a field into the "Sessions" tab ?

e.g :

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="partner_sessions_form_view">
    <field name="name">partner.sessions.name</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="/form/notebook/page[@string='Notes']" position="after">
        <page string="Sessions">
            <field name="session_ids" nolabel="1" colspan="4"/>
        </page>
    </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

This adds a page, but how would I add a field in the page **Sessions** ?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? Could you mark one of the answers offered here as the way you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a field to page 'Sessions' that you have created above, then you should provide

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="partner_sessions_form_view_again_inherited">
    <field name="name">partner.sessions.name.inherited</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="partner_sessions_form_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='session_ids']" position="before">
            <field name="new_field1" nolabel="1" colspan="4"/>
    </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

if you want to add add a field to the session_ids tree or form view, then

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='session_ids']/tree/field[@name='already_existing_field']" position="after">
    <field name="new_field1" />
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find that field in side you page Session
like this (but that page has to be their in view):

```
 <xpath expr="//page[@string='Sessions']/field[@name='some_field'] position="after">
     <field name="session_ids" nolabel="1" colspan="4"/>
 </xpath>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is covered pretty well in [the documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_3.html#inheritance-in-views). The simplest case is to just add your new field after an existing one. In this example, you're placing the `relation_ids` field after the `lang` field.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_partner_form4">
    <field name="name">res.partner.form.inherit4</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="lang" position="after">
            <field name="relation_ids"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

If that field appears in more than one place, you'll have to use [an XPath element](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_3.html#xpath-element). For example, if the `lang` field appears in a subview's tree view and its form view.